# Почему нет альтернативных компиляторов Java?

Tags: java, компилятор, javac, openjdk

Для многих языков есть куча реализаций, от самых простых, до вполне продвинутых. Но вот для Java есть только 3.5 альтернативы, да и те заброшены где-то во времена Java 5, а то и раньше. Почему? Быть может, есть какие-то лицензионные ограничения со стороны Sun/Oracle?